# Populate list of values from a range of cells based on certain value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet like this

[image]

I have xlookup formula like this in another sheet.

```
=xlookup(1,F5:F10,E5:E10)
```

With this formula, I can get the first total amount of sales rep id 1.

What I want is that the sheet to have list of all total amounts who has sales rep id as 1.

How to modify the formula such that it will reflect this?  With the current formula, if I paste in other cells, it always gives the first match which is $12.24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=FILTER(E5:E10,F5:F10=1)
```

Comment: In this example E5:E10 are filtered if the condition matches.  What if I want to also filter the corresponding entries from D5:D10?

Comment: use: =FILTER(D5:E10,F5:F10=1)